# Can't stop a process on the printer

Tags: 17.10, printing

I'm having troubles on stopping a printing process. Does anyone knows how to stop a printing process?

I'm using ubuntu 17.10 and the printer is a HP Deskjet InkAdvantage 2545. But it's not the only printer I'm having trouble stopping a process.

[image: Gif of the error I'm having]

Comment: You could use the CUPS `cancel` command (from the terminal), or use `ps -fu lp` to see all the processes involved in printing, and the `kill` command to kill them.

Comment: @waltinator thanks, canceling from CUPS did the trick.

Comment: I also face such problems. Is it a bug? Hope Canonical fix it in next 18.04 LTS release.

Comment: I guess it is. Because I keep on encounter the error time after time. But opening local CUPS and deleting the job works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Goto cups local 641.  Scroll to bottom after clicking on printers. click the link at bottom. Right click on your printer and choose View Print Q.  Click the x to delete the print job.

You can also choose your printer from the cups page and click cancel all jobs.